# Подключение к URL в Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift3

можно ли преобразовать этот код так чтобы получать JSON с URL а не просто с файла который находится в приложении

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
        let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
            (data, response, error) -> Void in
            do{
            guard error == nil,
                let responseData = data,
                let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else {
                    return
                }
            //handle object
            //print(jsonObject)
            if let postsArray = jsonObject?["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
                self.posts = [Post]()
                for postDictionary in postsArray {
                    let post = Post()
                    post.setValuesForKeys(postDictionary)
                    self.posts.append(post)
                    print("\(post.image2)")
                }
                }

            }catch let err { print(err) }
        }
        dataTask.resume()
```

Если да, подскажите пожалуйста как, а то сам что то немогу догнать. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Если Вам просто получить данные с GET, тогда вот Вам заготовка:

```
let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "YOURURL")!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
    (data, response, error) -> Void in
    guard error == nil, 
        let responseData = data, 
        let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers) else {
        //handle error if needed
        return
    }
    //handle object
    print(jsonObject)
}
dataTask.resume()
```

Comment: мне нужно получить данные а потом их распарсить вот в том виде как я запостил, непоскажете как это все вместе соборать

Comment: что то типо вот этого должно получится? он парсит все правильно но почему то выдает ошибку  appdelegatelogin[2495:70413] Unknown class ViewController in Interface Builder file.

Comment: let urlRequest = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "")!, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10)
let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) {
(data, response, error) -> Void in
let responseData = data,
let jsonObject = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: responseData, options: .mutableContainers) as? [String: Any] else {
return
}
if let postsArray = jsonObject?["data"] as? [[String: AnyObject]] {
self.posts = [Post]()
for postDictionary in postsArray {
let post = Post()
post.setValuesForKeys(postDictionary)
self.posts.append(post)
}
}

Comment: @Sergey Дополните пожалуйста вопрос отформатированным кодом.

Comment: не получается отформатировать не могу понять почему @VAndrJ

Comment: я изменю изначальный код посмотрите там пожалуйста @VAndrJ

Comment: @Sergey по коду вроде нормально, Вы говорите парсит нормально? А когда падает? Проверьте, все ли правильно прописано в интерфейс билдере.

Comment: парсит все правильно но на экран ничего невыводит

Comment: билдил все через viewController @VAndrJ

Comment: ошибка где то здесь точно потому что с локальным JSON все работает правильно @VAndrJ

Comment: @Sergey можете написать url, с которого берете данные для JSON?